# Disable showing full text on hover in Safari

Tags: jquery, css, safari, hover, jquery-ui-tooltip

I have the following code ([JSBin](https://jsbin.com/dinehaduku/2/edit?html,output)) which works well in Chrome. When we hover on the text, it shows the full text by JQuery tooltip.

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/themes/base/jquery-ui.css">
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.js"></script>
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
  <div class="mightOverflow" style="width: 100px; overflow: hidden; text-overflow: ellipsis; white-space: nowrap;">
    <a href="https://www.google.com">very very very very very very very very very very very long</a>
  </div>
  <script>
    $(function() {
        $(document).tooltip();
    });
    $(document).on('mouseenter', '.mightOverflow', function() { 
        var $t = $(this); 
        var title = $t.attr('title'); 
        if (!title) { 
            if (this.offsetWidth < this.scrollWidth) 
                $t.attr('title', $t.text()) 
        } else { 
            if (this.offsetWidth >= this.scrollWidth && title == $t.text()) 
                $t.removeAttr('title') 
        } 
    });
  </script>
</body>
</html>
```

However, it does not work in the same way in Chrome: Not only it displays the JQuery tooltip hover text, but also the default (smaller) full text on hover.

Does anyone know how I could disable this default hover effect in Safari?

Answer (score 0):

```
pointer-events: none;
```

May do the trick, but if it's an actual link you'll need to handle the request via JS.

Comment: it does not work. And indeed, I do need it to work with actual link. I will modify the OP.